# FreeMarker how to call object.toString() method in template

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to do something like that:

<#list exception.cause.stackTrace as stack>${stack}

and something like that:

<#list exception.cause.stackTrace as stack>${stack.toString()}

and had no success.
Someone knows how to call toString() method in my case? Thanks...

P.S. hm in preview mode site cuts closing list tag

Answer (score 3):

For objects whose class isn't treated specially by FreeMarker (examples of classes treated specially are `Number`, `List`, arrays, `Map`, etc.) simply printing the object with `${someObject}` calls `toString()` internally. If the objet is something that's treated specially (like a custom `List` subclass), then you will have to write `${myCustomList?api.toString()}`.

Last not least, there's the possibility of extending `DefaultObjectWrapper` to alter the behavior of FreeMarker.